# Extract all the valid URL string inside an element (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, substring

This is probably easy but I'm not very good with javascript especially regex. I know there is a method of getting the substring with either `.substr()` or `.substring()`. It's easy for me if I know the index location of the url strings but the text is loaded from the database.

Sample html:

```
<div>
 <p>Some text text text text http://stackoverflow.com text text 
   text http://google.com text text text.
 </p>
</div>
```

I want each url string to push inside an array as an output.

```
var mystrings = new Array
var text = $('p').text();
var url = text.substr()//don't know the logic here
mystrings.push(url);
//output
mystrings[0] == 'http://stackoverflow.com'
mystrings[1] == 'http://google.com'
```

I also found this regex but I don't know how to incorporate it:

```
var regexp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7hCD/).  Use [`RegExp.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) to execute the regular expression on your `text` variable.  Since you have the `g` global modifier on the expression, the `while` loop will go over each matched URL in the String.

```
var mystrings = new Array;

var text = $('p').text();
var regexp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;

while (matches = regexp.exec(text))
{
    mystrings.push(matches[0]);
}

console.log(mystrings);
// ["http://stackoverflow.com", "http://google.com"]
```